# link color should remain same when clicked until clicking on another link in menu and revert its color again

Tags: css

I want to make make menu such that when I click on menu item, active menu item text color should remain same as hovering effect... I used a:active but it works only till page/content gets opened... once page gets opened its effect is lost.. What should I do..??

Suppose I'm having 'black' color as default for menu item text color, its color changes to 'white' on hovering and again 'black' when content gets loaded.. It should remain 'white' until I click on another menu item i.e. 'active' menu item should persist its color.(this should be the case for all menu items). What will I have to do to achieve this effect?

I'm new to javascript and jquery....

Comment: Could you post the HTML/CSS/JavaScript you've used so far? Maybe build an example using jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

If, when you click, the page re-loads, then you need to somehow, in your back-end code, add a classname (say "selected") to the selected element. Then apply the same CSS rules to that element as :hover.

Otherwise, if you're not refreshing the page, and relying on jQuery to maintain a 'selected' type of state, do something like this:

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){
    $('#menu li').removeClass('selected'); // remove selected from any other item first
    (this).addClass('selected'); //add selected to the one just clicked.
});
```

CSS

```
#menu li{color:black;background:white;}    
#menu li:hover, #menu li.selected{     
    color:white;background:black;    
    /* CSS properties here will be applied to both hovered */    
    /* and last-clicked item*/     
}
```

Comment: guys this doesn't provide solution it will work only if there is no reloading involved

Answer (score 1):

you should use class sequence

1-a:link

2-a:visited

3-a:hover

4-a:active

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Faust, your solution really worked for me.  One quick edit though, I think there needs to be a "$" symbol in front of the "(this)," or at least that's what worked for me. So:

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){
    $('#menu li').removeClass('selected'); // remove selected from any other item first
    $(this).addClass('selected'); //add selected to the one just clicked.
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work when page reloads the jquery effect vanishes :(*